# Can't create table `socialnetwork`.`login_tokens` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, sql

My database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `login_tokens`;

CREATE TABLE `login_tokens` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `token` (`token`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `login_tokens_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table users
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1005 - Can't create table `socialnetwork`.`login_tokens` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: your login_tokens table is looking for users table, which has not been created yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the table `users` **before** creating the table `login_tokens`.

At the time you are creating `login_tokens`, `users` does not yet exist, so there's no way of creating the "foreign key" relationship.